# Handle multiple camera capture UWP

Tags: c#, .net, camera, uwp

I'm working with a Universal application that let we capture an image for each camera (two or more). So do we have any ways to manage all camera capture stream sand process it? I just found the tutorial about individual camera handling in MSDN.

I found some article about manage multiple IP cameras in Winforms but nothing for UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know, for UWP app, the simplest way to capture photos and video is using the [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) class. See [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture).

In this official sample [Camera frames sample](http://Camera%20frames%20sample), it shows how to list all capture source and access camera with different profile.

> So do we have any ways to manage all camera capture stream sand
>   process it?

We can initialize multiple `MediaCapture` instances and read frame by using `MediaFrameReader` Class. **Check out this [wrapper](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraFrames/cs/FrameRenderer.cs#L48) to see how to process frame as you need**.

**Share a multiple camera sample based on the above official sample: [Github LINK](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/MultipleCameraFrames)**

The screenshot(Running on my laptop which connected a Microsoft Life Camera HD-3000):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try it for now and let you know later.

Comment: How can I get information about a port of all cameras? I want to separate it by port number.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy Please ask a new question, not related to this one, we will have a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037240/get-port-number-all-of-connected-usb-cameras-in-uwp