# How to use two CameraCaptureUI at the same time (UWP / C++)

Tags: c++, concurrency, uwp, video-capture, uwp-xaml

I am working on a Universal Windows Platform Application (UWP) in which I am using C++ as the main language. I want to read from two cameras at the same time. One camera belongs to the Kinect RGB camera and the other to the Kinect Depth camera. So far I've managed to read from just one using this piece of code:

```
void SDKTemplate::Scenario4_ReproVideo::Grabar_Click(Platform::Object^ 
sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
CameraCaptureUI^ dialog = ref new CameraCaptureUI();
dialog->VideoSettings->Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat::Mp4;

Windows::Foundation::Collections::IPropertySet^ appSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values;

concurrency::task<StorageFile^>(dialog->CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode::Video)).then([this](StorageFile^ file) {
    if (file != nullptr) {

        concurrency::task<Streams::IRandomAccessStream^> (file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read)).then([this] (Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream){
            CapturedVideo->SetSource(stream, "video/mp4");
            logger->Text = "recording";
        });
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IPropertySet^ appSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values;

        appSettings->Insert("CapturedVideo", PropertyValue::CreateString(file->Path));
    }
    else {
        logger->Text = "Something went wrong or was cancelled";
    }

});
}
```

By doing this I can reliably record from one of the cameras. My problem is that I need to record from both cameras at the same time as I need the Depth and RGB to process the video.

I am new to concurrency, is there a way (the simpler the better) to achieve two recordings simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP app, we can capture photos and video using the [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture) class which provides functionality for capturing photos, audio, and videos from a capture device. See the topic [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture).

We can initialize multiple [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture) instances then read frame by using [MediaFrameReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.Frames.MediaFrameReader) Class.  see the topic [Discover and select camera capabilities with camera profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-profiles) and [Process media frames with MediaFrameReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader) and also look into the official sample [CameraFrames](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames).

Besides, there is a similar thread about UWP multiple camera capture, you can also refer it:

[Handle multiple camera capture UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083374/handle-multiple-camera-capture-uwp)